How to number and cross-reference equations in an R vignette?
(This Q is somewhat related to: How to have `pkgdown` use figure numbers and cross-references in vignettes?)
In an R vignette I want to demonstrate generation of LaTeX with new functions in my matlib package, http://friendly.github.io/matlib/.
symbolicMatrix() and Eqn() generate this LaTeX:
> symbolicMatrix(lhs = "\\mathbf{X}") |> Eqn(label="eq:X")

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:X}
\mathbf{X} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
  x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1m} \\ 
  x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2m} \\ 
  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 
  x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \cdots & x_{nm} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

This works fine in an .Rmd document with PDF output, but I can't get it to work in an HTML vignette. The output from my MWE (below) looks like this -- no equation number, no cross-ref

Here is the code for my example:
---
title: "Can I Number Equations in a Vignette?"
author: An Author
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
  base_format: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Can I Number Equations in a Vignette?}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
library(matlib)
```


```{r results='asis'}
symbolicMatrix(lhs = "\\mathbf{X}") |> Eqn(label="eq:X")
```

Can I reference this as: See \ref{eq:X}

